# Programmatically setting WPF style to baseline style

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF project where I am dynamically setting the Style of certain elements programmatically in my ViewModel.

I'm defining my Style properties like so:

```
private static Style okTextStyle = Application.Current.FindResource("SimpleTextBox") as Style;
private static Style errorTextStyle = Application.Current.FindResource("SimpleTextBoxError") as Style;

private Style keyTypeValueMeaningStyle = okTextStyle;
public Style KeyTypeValueMeaningStyle
{
    get { return keyTypeValueMeaningStyle; }
    set
    {
        keyTypeValueMeaningStyle = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("KeyTypeValueMeaningStyle"));
    }
}

// ...later in the code...

if (error)
{
    ...
    KeyTypeValueMeaningStyle = errorTextStyle;
}
else
{
    ...
    KeyTypeValueMeaningStyle = okTextStyle;
}
```

And using it in my XAML like so:

```
Style="{Binding KeyTypeValueMeaningStyle, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

This all works perfectly fine; however, I'm trying to streamline a bit more and instead of having `okTextStyle` set to a named style in my ResourceDictionary, I simply want it set to my base `TextBox` style defined in my ResourceDictionary, but I don't know if this is possible.

I've tried setting to null or blank such as this, but it does not work.

```
private static Style okTextStyle = null As Style;
```

I've also tried doing similar things in my `else` block but it doesn't work either.  I'm guessing that since in my XAML I'm always defining a style, it wants a valid style reference in there, not just a null or blank value.

Admittedly, this is a First-World programming issue as everything is working fine.  But the `SimpleTextBox` definition is just a duplicate of the baseline style at this point and I'm trying to streamline a bit if possible and not have duplicate styles.  Can this be done?

Comment: Yeah, that's not MVVM...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Application.Current.FindResource(typeof(TextBox));
```

If you want to be a little more persnickety, look at [`FrameworkElement.DefaultStyleKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.defaultstylekey(v=vs.110).aspx).

That said, this is not something that a viewmodel ought to be responsible for.

By the way, `null As Style` returns exactly the same `null` as `null` without the cast. If I were on the C# team, I would have the compiler give you an Otiose Cast Warning on that line. That's not the only reason I'll never be on the C# team, but it's a good place to start.

Comment: I understand the comments about poor use of the MVVM pattern because the viewmodel shouldn't drive the UI; however, I haven't really seen a consensus approach to binding UI properties through MVVM.  Every option I've seen either requires the viewmodel to drive some aspect of the UI, or reliance on the viewmodel communicating with the view codebehind.  There doesn't seem to be (that I can find) a pattern that has wide acceptance.

Comment: @bassrek I'd do some kind of theme thing with `DynamicResource`. Another option (maybe this is what you're doing already) is to at least separate out the Style stuff into a separate global theme "viewmodel".